# Make a redirect of url with ?id=(VAR)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I try all posible, i need redirect this url's type:

```
http://www.midominio.com/esp/productos_listado.php?id=98
```

with id [1-4504] To

```
http://www.midominio.com/categorias/98-libro.html
```

I prove:

```
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=([0-9]+)
    RewriteRule ^id=(.*)$ /categoria/%1$1-libro.html? [R=301]
```

But only rewrite:

```
http://www.midominio.com/categorias/-libro.html
```

Without var nu,be

Comment: It is unclear in what direction you want to rewrite. So what is the actually requested URL and what should it be rewritten to internally?

Comment: midominio.com/esp/product?id=(var number) I would redirect to midomain.com/categorias/(var number)-book.html

Comment: Which did not answer my question, the vagueness stays. So I added an answer with _both_ alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear from your description in what direction you actually want the rewriting to be applied.

If the incoming request to be rewritten is `/categorias/...`, then something like this should be just fine:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?categorias/(\d+)-libro.html /esp/productos_listado.php?id=$1 [L]
```

If however, as your phrasing suggests, you have the unusual situation that you want to rewrite incoming requests to `/esp/productos_listado.php`, then try it this way 'round:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^/?esp/productos_listado\.php /categorias/%1-libro.html [L]
```

That notation would be working for `.htaccess` style files and also in the real host configuration. Note that if you have access to the host configuration, then you *always* should prefer placing the rules in there. `.htaccess` style files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they *really* slow the http server down. They are only offered for situations where people do *not* have access to the host configuration. So for example when using really cheap hosting service providers...

Comment: Ok, you solve my problem, i modify your code, and solve. Thank you:
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^esp/productos_listado\.php$ /categorias/%1-libro.html? [L,R=301]